# Why can't I access local class outside declaring method?

Tags: java, nested, inner-classes

I recently bumped into a rare -- but perfectly legal syntax: [Local Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

I was wondering why can't I access a local class outside that method? With what is it different from an inner class which can be access in the outer class or with an enclosed object (`outer.new Inner()`)?

Example: this is perfectly valid,

```
//this is valid
public class Outer {
    int outer_x = 100;

    public void test() {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();

    }

    public class Inner {
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("Outer x is: " + outer_x);
        }
    }
}
```

This is valid as well

```
 //this is valid as well
public class Outer {
    int outer_x = 100;

    public void test() {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();
    }

    public class Inner {
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("Outer x is: " + outer_x);
        }
    }

    public void test2() {

        Inner inner2 = new Inner();
        inner2.display();
    }
}
```

But this will not compile:

```
public class Outer {
    int outer_x = 100;

    public void test() {

        class Inner {

            public void display() {
                System.out.println("Outer x is: " + outer_x);
            }
        }
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();

    }

    public void test2() {

        Inner inner2 = new Inner(); // error here
        inner2.display();
    }
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Because you can't access a class that is only defined in another method. You'd have to give it scope.

Comment: I know! My question is "why".

Comment: @EFFKAY The same reason you can't access `inner` outside the method it's declared in. Scope.

Comment: You can define an Annonymous class inside a function, but not a named class

Comment: @smac89 Ah, [but you can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

Comment: @shmosel, I stand corrected. Blimey

Comment: But I can define a class inside a function if the class is just nested within a class. why?

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: What is the difference between example 1 and example 3. I know the difference, I am asking "why".

Comment: One is limited to the scope of a method, because that's where you declared it.

Comment: Your question is beginning to sound like, "Why can't I declare a class wherever I want?" Do you not see the difference between example 1 and 3? One of them has the class declared in another class, while the other has declared the class inside a function. The question you should be asking first and foremost is, "Is it possible to declare a class inside a function?", and if the answer is "YES", then you should ask, "In what circumstances can I do so?"

Comment: On closer inspection, it clearly looks like you try to access the class from a scope outside of where it was created i.e. inside `test`. So the question you should be asking should be, "Is it possible to access a class defined in another method, from a different method", and the answer to that is definitely NOT. Reason? Scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every call to `test()` creates a complete new version of the class. Therefore it may access (final or effectively final) local variables!

Here's a rundown what's going on.

```
public class Outer {

    public void test(int i) {
        class Inner {
            private int x = i; // i may be different on each call of test

            public void display() {
                System.out.println("Inner x is: " + x);
            }
        }
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();
    }

    public void test2() {
        test(1); // prints 1
        test(2); // prints 2

        //now imagine this is valid
        Inner inner2 = new Inner();
        inner2.display();// what's the value of x??
    }
}
```

Comment: *Because every call to `test()` creates a complete new version of the class.* Not really. It's one class that gets instantiated with different values. Kind of like how an inner class is instantiated with a reference to an instance of its outer class. But good demonstration of why local classes are scoped.